# Convert a conditional formatting formula into an ARRAYFORMULA to display text on first occurrence of duplicate

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create an ARRAYFORMULA for a column that will display text if the value in Column A is unique, and if it is a duplicate display text indicating if the value is the first occurrence of a duplicate or a subsequent occurrence of it.

I've been able to do this with a (probably overly complicated) formula that works as a fill, but because it uses INDIRECT, it can't be iterated over using ARRAYFORMULA.

I came across the following conditional formatting formula on [this site](https://officebeginner.com/gsheet/how-to-highlight-duplicates-in-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=Method%203%3A%20Highlight%20the%20Duplicates%20Except%20The%20First%20Instance) that highlights all instances of duplicates *except the first occurrence*:

`=countif($A$2:$A2,$A2) > 1` Where of course Column A contains the value we're checking.

I'm hoping to use this in an IF statement inside an ARRAYFORMULA to run on all the values that are not unique, but I just don't get why the formula works or how to adapt it to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A)=1,"Great! I'm unique!",IF(MATCH(A2:A,A:A,0)=ROW(A2:A),"I'm the first instance!", "I'm just a clone..")),""))
```

[image]